# Генерация кода assembler для foreach

Tags: c++, ассемблер, кодогенераторы

Пишу программу, которая генерирует код ассемблера для конструкции foreach (... in ...) { ... }

Имеется дерево синтаксического разбора, в одной ветке содержится foreach и круглые скобки, в другой всё что внутри фигурных скобок.

Как можно описать конструкцию для первой ветки? А именно для того, что находится в скобках.

Вот код и скриншот с выводом дерева разбора + сгенерированный код второй ветки.

```
void generateCode() {
        rightTree->generateCode1();
        leftTree->generateCode1();
    }

void generateCode1()
    {
        if (key == "foreach")
        {
            cout << "FOREACH" << endl;
            //rightTree->generateCode2();
            return;
        }
        if (key == "{ }")
        {
            rightTree->generateCode2();
            return;
        }
    }
    void generateCode2()
    {
        if (key == "=")
        {
            leftTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSTORE " << rightTree->key << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (key == "+")
        {
            rightTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSTORE $" << number << endl;
            leftTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tADD $" << number << endl;
            number++;
            return;
        }
        if (key == "-")
        {
            rightTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSTORE $" << number << endl;
            leftTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSUB $" << number << endl;
            number++;
            return;
        }
        if (key == "*")
        {
            rightTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSTORE $" << number << endl;
            leftTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tMUL $" << number << endl;
            number++;
            return;
        }
        if (key == "/")
        {
            rightTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tSTORE $" << number << endl;
            leftTree->generateCode2();
            cout << "\tDIV $" << number << endl;
            number++;
            return;
        }
        if (key[0] >= '0' && key[0] <= '9')
        {
            cout << "\tLOAD =" << key << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << "\tLOAD " << key << endl;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/pocable/MIPS-Algorithms/blob/master/Miscellaneous/ForEach.s посмотрите как это реализовано здесь, может быть вам это будет полезно.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Я бы рассматривал foreach как обычный while который выполняет свой блок кода (операнд 2) пока выражение операнд1 (который он то же выполняет) возвращает истину. При этом foreach для операнда1 предоставляет контекст, в котором бинарный оператор `in` представляет из себя итератор присваивающий своему левому операнду очередное значение из правого операнда и возвращающий истину, если присвоение удалось сделать (список не закончился)

Comment: ну либо признать `in` ключевым словом, являющимся обязательным для foreach и разделяющего первый и второй операнды foreatch. Блок кода при этом считать третьим операндом foreach

Comment: И да, не рекомендую рассматривать фигурные скобки как составляющую часть foreach. Их гораздо удобней рассматривать как конструкцию возвращающую блок кода, который можно выполнять (и возможно предоставляющую область видимости для этого блока кода, если области видимости предполагаются описываемым языком). А foreach просто требует по синтаксису наличия в этом месте выполнимого кода

Comment: А что бы это в ассемблер переводить надо решить как в вашем языке работают массивы (или списки или еще что то содержащее более 1 элемента). foreach с точки зрения ассемблера организует цикл, т.е. выводит метку для возврата в эту точку, потом код который проверяет условие и возможно прокручивает массив и в самом конце после блока кода генерит возврат к метке и метку для выхода из цикла